# NodeJS/ExpressJS api findById returns null

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, rest

**This is my code in the controller**

```js
const getById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const myId = Inventory.findById(id).exec();
    res.json(myId);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json({
      message: error
    });
  }
};
```

**My router**

```js
 router.get('/details/:id', homeController.getById);
```

Comment: You might need to cast your id to type of ObjectId.

Comment: did you try using `req.params.id` instead of `id` in your `getById` function?

Answer (score 0):

You have the issues. First is that you are not waiting for `findById()` to return the result. You should wait for it and then return the response. Second is that you are passing `id` which is not defined. You should pass `req.params.id` instead.

```
const myId = await Inventory.findById(req.params.id).exec();
```

Comment: Hi Nenad ,thanks for getting in touch, I added await and I'm still getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a null result because it is returning the response before it has processed the request. Looks like you need a Promise or Callback here also where is the id your trying to pass. I'm assuming a lot about your setup so if this does not work, please give more detail to your question

Example

```js
const getById = async (req, res) => {
    // We need the id we are going to pass from the request
    id = req.body.id;
    try {
        // Because nodejs is asyncronise we need to add a block such as a promise
        async function info() {
            data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var info = Inventory.findById(id).exec();
                resolve(info);
            })
            return await data;
        }
        // now we can call the promise and wait for the response before we send the json
        const myId = await info();
        res.json(myId);
    } catch (error) {
        res.json({
            message: error
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it! Would you mind clicking the accepted answer if you're satisfied. Need the rep points. lol! Have a great evening.